# Sound, login, desktop, etc are all broken. Should I reinstall Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, unity, sound, login, themes

I'm using ubuntu 14.04 with unity. It seems I installed something and then turn off pc like always. Today I started ubuntu and the system froze just before the login screen. I did everything I could to solve this issue but things got worse, so I tried uninstalling unity and installing gnome. I can only start the desktop from console (startx) but a lot ot stuff fails (sound, trying to install a theme, etc) and login still fails (screen freezes). All these errors seem to be related since they appeared together.
In your experience, should I reinstall everything from scratch or is it feasible to solve all these issues one by one? (asking here) I would like to login as usual, have sound and install a custom theme.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Based upon what you've said, yes, do a re-install.

If you want to save your data, boot from a live CD and copy the contents of your `/home` folder to an external drive.

Then re-install, and once booted, you can copy your data back to the internal disk.